# Haskell list length alternative

Tags: list, haskell

Hi I've got a list on Haskell with close to 10^15 Int's in it and I'm trying print the length of the list.

```
let list1 = [1..1000000000000000]   --  this is just a dummy list I dont
print list1 length                  --  know the actual number of elements
```

printing this takes a very long time to do, is there another way to get the number of elements in the list and print that number?

Comment: No, there isn't. You will need to use a smarter algorithm so that you don't actually use a list.

Comment: Or at least so you don't need the length. Either way, this seems like an XY Problem and I think you would benefit from asking how to solve your problem rather than how to implement the solution you have in mind.

Comment: Haskell lists are just linked lists. Just a pile of cons cells (using the `:` constructor) with (possibly) a terminal `[]`.  There's no way to tell how many cons cells there are without counting. If O(n) is too high a cost to pay for length, and you don't want to store it yourself, chances are you should be using a different data structure.  I agree with @ReinHenrichs tho that you should post the problem you're trying to use list length to solve, since there may be an alternate approach that would be faster.

Comment: Because the list is an arithmetic sequence, you already know the length, which is `last list1 - head list1 + 1`.  No need to walk the whole linked list to obtain its length.

Comment: @HenriMenke It's a linked list: you can't get `last list1` without walking the entire list.

Comment: You may have a function that you expect to produce that many `Int`s, but I very much doubt you have an actual *list* of this many `Int`s. Such a list would require at least 4 *petabytes* of memory.

Answer (score 2):

I've occasionally gotten some value out of lists that carry their length. The poor man's version goes like this:

```
import Data.Monoid

type ListLength a = (Sum Integer, [a])

singletonLL :: a -> ListLength a
singletonLL x = (1, [x])

lengthLL :: ListLength a -> Integer
lengthLL (Sum len, _) = len
```

The `Monoid` instance that comes for free gives you empty lists, concatenation, and a `fromList`-alike. Other standard `Prelude` functions that operate on lists like `map`, `take`, `drop` aren't too hard to mimic, though you'll need to skip the ones like `cycle` and `repeat` that produce infinite lists, and `filter` and the like are a bit expensive. For your question, you would also want analogs of the `Enum` methods; e.g. perhaps something like:

```
enumFromToLL :: Integral a => a -> a -> ListLength a
enumFromToLL lo hi = (fromIntegral hi-fromIntegral lo+1, [lo..hi])
```

Then, in ghci, your example is instant:

```
> lengthLL (enumFromToLL 1 1000000000000000)
1000000000000000
```